# Define filter parameters dynamically in django queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-queryset

Suppose we have such a model:

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Can we put `x` as a variable inside the filter so that we can have different querysets by giving different args when calling the get_queryset function?

```
def get_queryset(x, y):
    queryset = Membership.objects.filter(x=y)
    return queryset
```

Comment: When will you call the `get_queryset`? In a class-based view, it is acalled by the view boilerplate.

Comment: Exactly *what* do you want to achieve? Right now you focus on *how* you want to achieve this, not what.

Answer (score 2):

A [**`Q`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) can take a 2-tuple with as first item a string that specifies the "*key*" and as second item the "*value*", so you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

x = 'person_id'
y = 14

Membership.objects.filter(Q((x, y)))
```

to obtain the `Membership`s with `person_id=14`.

It however does not make much sense to use this in `get_queryset` in a class-based view, because that function has to respect its code contract, and adding extra parameters will not work: it simply expects a `self`, and an optional `queryset`. You can add extra optional parameters, but when the view calls the `get_queryset` it will not use these parameters, or at least not if you do not alter the  boilerplate logic.